# Linux and rpms and apps best practices?

Tags: linux, package-management, rpm

I have an application to be delivered as an RPM.
I don't know very good Linux.
What is best. Should the application start automatically on RPM installation or should the user manually start it from /etc/init.d?

Comment: What kind of application is it and what kind of users will use it?

Comment: It is a tomcat and web apps in it.Users access it via web

Comment: So, it seems to be made for at least semi-professional users, therefore I recommend /etc/init.d.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fedora has what is probably [the best initscript policies](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:SysVInitScript), which covers your situation:

> ### Why don't we....
>
> - run 'chkconfig <service> on'?
>
> If a service should be enabled by default, make this the default in the init script. Doing otherwise will cause the service to be turned on on upgrades if the user explicitly disabled it.
>
> Note that the default for most network-listening scripts is off. This is done for better security. We have multiple tools that can enable services, including GUIs.
>
> - start the service after installation?
>
> Installations can be in changeroots, in an installer context, or in other situations where you don't want the services started.

Answer (score 0):

You should add it to  /etc/init.d, but make it also run as a service. Search google for tomcat service script

Answer (score 0):

Be careful, "RPM based distribution" doesn't mean that a RPM built for one of them will work on another one of the set.

Note that Fedora now uses [systemd](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Systemd), that changes how things are done. Look at the [Fedora packaging guidelines](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Guidelines).